# Cannot output scope properties

Tags: angularjs, scope

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Vrev.png)

Hi, I have "loc" properties in scope, but I cannot output to console "loc" Array

in directive:

```
return {
        scope:{
            loc:'='
        },
        template: '<div id="gmaps"></div>',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
              var map, infoWindow;
              var markers = [];
              var defaultLoc =  new google.maps.LatLng(49.233614,28.47646199999997);
              console.log(scope);
              console.log(scope.loc);// undefined
```

Controller:

```
 navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
    $scope.$apply(function() {

      $scope.loc = [{ latitude:position.coords.latitude}, {longitude:position.coords.longitude}] ;
     });
  }
```

HTML:

```
 <div hi-loc loc="loc"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's the way you are using the scope..
If you need two way data binding, keep the scope like that, but try using

```
attrs.loc
```

If you don't need to change the loc variable, just change the scope to:

```
scope:{
    loc:'@'
}
```

Hope it works :)

Answer (score 0):

At the point in time that you are logging to the console, the `scope.loc` property in the controller is still `undefined`, as you do not set it until inside the `$scope.$apply()` call - the contents of which execute on the next `$digest` cycle.

The reason you are able to still able to see the `loc` property on the full scope object in the console is because Chrome is keep a "living reference" to that object in memory, and your `loc` property is being populated by the time you can see it (but after your explicit `console.log(scope.loc)`

You could use an explicit watcher on the property, and log the new value to the console instead:

```
scope.$watch(function() { return scope.loc }, function(newVal) {
   console.log(newVal)
})
```